# The left mouse button has stopped working properly

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

Suddenly my left mouse button has got a very strange behaviour.

I can run applications by clicking the items in the main menu, can close them using the cross at the top right hand corner... But I cannot press any other control buttons on the windows of running applications. When I am using Chromium and perform a click on a web page, another web page (it seems one of the recently used) replaces the current one. I have to write this message from my mobile.

What I did is to run xev to know whether the left button is working phisically or not. All the clicks (the up and down events) are catched, so it seems that it is not a hardware issue.

But I noticed that the left button clicks generate events for two buttons: "button 1" and "button 8" simultaniously. If "button 8" is something related to the back action, it could explain the unexpected replacing web pages in Chromium. But if it is the reason, what could happen with my system?

Some other details. The last aplications I had worked with before the problem came in were vim, LibbreOffice Writer, Chromium, Nemo, System monitor... The edit mode for the panel is off. There is another account on my machine -- it has the same problem, so it is a system wide issue. The system is Linux Mint, I have used it for years without any troubles.

Comment: Does this occur with a different mouse?

Comment: Try another mouse, and also try (if one is available) a newer mouse driver to see if that has any effect.

Comment: I have got only this one. I can buy a new one but tomorrow. The shops have already closed.

Comment: Sometimes the micro switches go bad in mice.

Comment: The mouse button works. It does not work properly but it works. Right now I  have loaded a steam game -- everything is in order. Menu items in applications works too. But  the buttons in applications and the links on web pages do not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has solved by itself.

I didn’t do anything. This morning I have tested the mouse in all situations — everything is fine.

But I immediately looked at the output of the “xev” utility and found that my assumption about the cause was correct — there is no mention of “button 8” anymore. Clicks with the left button generate information only about “button 1”. I’m sure that was the source of my strange troubles.

So, other questions come next. What was it? What (or perhaps even “who” :) was changing the system files? How to prevent it in the future? And what to do if it happens again?

I thank everyone who responded for your attention and time!